# Select HTML Menu Item via VBA

Tags: html, browser-automation

I'm fairly new to HTML, so please bear with me on this. I am using Excel VBA to interact with an website, with the intent to automate this interaction.

**Problem Statement**

I have a web page with (what looks like) a button that I need to click on. In the HTML it is listed as a Menu Item. Im able to successfully click other buttons on the page, but those have < button > tags.

I have tried to use the click method by selecting it by ID but I get an 'Object Variable or With block variable not set' error.

```
Sub WD_auto()
    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLSel As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://wd3.myworkday.com/redacted/d/home.htmld"

    Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
    Set HTMLSel = HTMLDoc.getElementById("88831e18a0894109a83c10bc9a9be6c7")
    HTMLSel.Click
End Sub
```

The block of HTML that i think i need to interact with is shown below.

```
<div class="GNMRENADFGC GNMRENADBHC GNMRENADHHC" tabindex="-2" 
id="88831e18a0894109a83c10bc9a9be6c7" role="menuitem" 
aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="3">
```

Any pointers or literature would be appreciated.

Comment: You have not added a `runat="server"` clause so the server does not know the div even exists or can be interacted with. If you set a breakpoint and step through the code, I bet you'd find that `HTMLDoc.getElementById` is returning null.

Comment: Hello Joel, thank you for your reply. You're correct, stepping through shows HTMLDOC.getElementsByID is null. However, I don't see the runat attribute mentioned in the HTML Header or Body. How would I go about modifying my code to introduce this clause? Many Thanks

Comment: Typically you would have your .vb page attached to your .aspx page in the very first line of the page like so `<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="pagename.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>` and then you would add the `runat="server'` attribute to the <div> element `<div runat="server" class=...` and so forth. I hope this helps. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_web_programming.htm for more information if this is confusing.

Comment: Ignore previous comment. I only just realized you are using Excel VBA for this. What are you trying to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some more research i have **a** solution. I am just looping all the `div` tags and checking the `Inner Text` property of each until I find the one I want to click.

It works, but if anyone has a more elegant solution I'm all ears. The loop seems a bit wasteful, I would prefer to just refer directly to, and then click the element.

```
    Set ElementsA = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("div")

    For Each ElementA In ElementsA
        On Error Resume Next
        If ElementA.innerText = "User Name and Password login" Then
            ElementA.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ElementA
```